# mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, resource given in ~\index.php on line 46

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Here is the code that is giving me the **Warning**

```
$query = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
$uname_check = mysqli_num_rows($query);
```

What is the problem here ?
Similar code elsewhere in the page is working.

Also, I am getting the following error in the next line of code:

```
mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in ~\index.php on line 47
```

Comment: Please show the code of your connection. And make sure you don't mix MySQL API's (`mysql_*` and `mysqli_*`)

Comment: `<?php
 $connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
 if (!$connection){
  die("Database Connection Failed" . mysql_error());
 }
 $select_db = mysql_select_db('s3f');
 if (!$select_db){
  die("Database Selection Failed" . mysql_error());
}`
This is the connection code

Comment: you cannot use mysql_connect with mysqli_* function o.o

Comment: You are using mysqli_query with mysql_connect... the two aren't compatible. Use mysqli (or, PDO is even better).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing MySQL API's ([`mysql_*`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php) and [`mysqli_*`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php))

You have to use something like this:

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","") or die ("could not connect");
```

And to select your database ([`mysqli_select_db`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.select-db.php)):

```
mysqli_select_db("s3f") or die ("no database");
```

Also for your connection error handling use ([`mysqli_connect_error()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.connect-error.php)):

```
mysqli_connect_error()
```

**Side note:**

If you're in a testing environment i would recommend you to put error reporting at the top of your file(s):

```
<?php
    ini_set("display_errors", 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
?>
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks that worked ... but it is still giving me an error saying it requires 2 parameters. So I added the connection as the second parameter as suggested on www.php.net
Now the same error of **mysqli** is back
Also ... Database Selection Failed !

Comment: @ShreyasTripathy Look carefully! When you're programming procedural (what you're doing) then the connection comes first and then the query! See: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Comment: @ShreyasTripathy You're welcome! (BTW: I would recommend you to search next time a little bit more! ;D e.g. this question was asked so many times before and there are so many solutions!)

Comment: Will do ! I have this project to submit I was quite frustrated